# Measurable function with parameters

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, measurable-functions, borel-measures

Let $\mu_{y}$ a Borel probability on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ indexed by a parameter $y \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$.

Let $A$ a borel set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and suppose that the map 
$$
F \text{ : } y \rightarrow \mu_{y}(A)
$$
is measurable (we equiped $\mathbb{R}$ with the borel algebra).

Let $T_{y} \text{ : } \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ a family of measurable functions indexed by a parameter $y \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$.

> My question is : Is the map $$ y \rightarrow \mu_{y}( T_{y} \in A) $$
>   measurable ?

Thanks and regards.

EDIT : We can suppose that $(x,y) \rightarrow T_{y}(x)$ is measurable if it helps. Maybe without this assumption we can say anything.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $n=d=1$, $A = [0,1]$, and $\mu_y$ to be the Lebesgue measure for each $y$. Then, $y \mapsto \mu_y$ is measurable (it is just constant). Let $N$ be a non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then, for $y \in N$, define $T_y: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $T_y(x) = x$, and for $y \not \in N$, define $T_y: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $T_y(x) = \frac{x}{100}$. Then, each $T_y$ is measurable but $\{y : \mu(T_y^{-1}([0,1])) \in [0,2]\} = N$ is non-measurable.

Comment: thank you but I edited two days ago, $(x,y) \rightarrow T_{y}(x)$ is measurable.

Comment: No you didn't. You put it after the main question and said you can suppose it if it helps. You didn't unconditionally say you suppose it, and you put it after the main question.

Comment: Because I felt there's nothing interesting we can say without this assumption.

Comment: I think the result could work with that assumption and that's the point. And I agree I should have been clearer thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm here to talk about this problem if you have any idea :).

Comment: I answered your question. If you post another question and provide a link to it here, I will think about it. However, I won't think about the question posted here anymore, since I have solved it. It is a pet peeve of mine when I spend time on a question to learn that the OP wanted an answer to a different question and did not make it clear. But I'm telling you right now that I will think about the other question if you do post a link to it here.

Comment: You answered to the easiest part. Thank you.

Comment: But I can see that it annoys you, and no big deal I will give you the points don't worry :). (If anyone else give answer to the main question).
I will just wait for answers and when the bouty will be closed I'll give you the point no big deal, I understand your time is precious ! :).